# Unique CSS for placement of elements (Pegs/Labels off an image), can it be done?

Tags: javascript, css, snap.svg

Have a situation that I am trying to figure out the best approach.

It consists of an image, then peg's pointing off reference points of the image w/ labels. I am attaching an image as an example.

[image: Example Image]

I have not mocked up code yet, still debating the best approach so I was hoping to get some input from the community.

Thoughts:

- Static use of top/left positioning: Issue there is this needs to be responsive. As the image scales, we lose accurate placement
- Javascript: Could try n use javascript to calculate the positions using ratio'd equations and jquerys .postition()
- SnapSVG (or similar), This is what I am playing with right now, create the lines/circles with snap and animate them in. I've never used it, so there is a learning curve.

Would love to hear some thoughts! Thank you

Comment: before you get a million downvotes, you might wanna provide sample(s) of what you've already tried that isn't working for you.

Comment: Seems, you already know the answer,  Two of your choices seem to come with caveats and one doesn't, If you need it ASAP then just go with what you already know how to do and deliver a solution, If its just for fun then take some time to explore all three options and see what each approach brings / doesn't bring and then go with what works best for you. .